# Livereload: Add script tag using Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, asp.net-core, grunt-contrib-watch

I have an ASP.net 5 project using Grunt, grunt-contrib-watch & livereload.

This is all working as expected which is awesome. 
Now I would like to use Grunt to insert the following code snippet:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

I have read that I can use a browser extension instead of the above. Ideally I would like like the above snippet inserted for a dev configuration only.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you looked at grunt-processhtml?

Comment: Thanks! that's a solution to my problem +1

Comment: great!  you might want to answer your own question here (with a code snippet) so that it helps the next person searching for a solution